# How do you name a function so that you can introspect it?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write a routine that appends the name of a function to #trace whenever it's called:

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var dom = {};
    var myObject = {};
    myObject.myFunction = {
        trace('myObject.myFunction');
        // function logic goes here
    }

    dom.trace = $('#trace');
    var trace = function(value) {
        dom.trace.append(value + '<br>'));
    }

    $(document).on('click','#Save',myObject.myFunction)
})(jQuery, window);
```

In this little proof-of-concept that I've thrown together, I know that I'm probably doing 12 things wrong.

But here's the point of my question:

Q: How do you name a function so that it can be introspected?

Comment: What is `introspected`?

Comment: Why don't you just use a debugger? You can get a function's name with `arguments.callee`, but it's being phased out (won't work in strict mode, may not work in future ECMAScript versions).

Comment: "won't work in strict mode". Oh.  That's probably what I've been hitting my head against.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm thinking about keeping a trace while it's out in the field to help me recreate the steps that the user took before getting an error.

Comment: @jfriend00, introspected is where I don't have to hard code the name of the function inside of every one of my functions.  I just want to call trace(arguments) and have function trace(value) compute what function it came from.

Comment: Read about `arguments.callee` and `arguments.callee.caller` in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).  But, be forewarned, all this is being removed and is already non-functional in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.learnjquery.org/tutorials/:

```
function show_props(a,b,c,d,e)
{
   var msg = "function name = " + arguments.callee.name + "\n";
   msg += "called from = " + show_props.caller.name + "\n";
   msg += "arguments.length = " + arguments.length + " argument(s) were passed.\n"
   msg += "show_props.length (arity) = " + show_props.length + " argument(s) are defined total.\n";
   msg += "arguments = " + arguments +  "\n";
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
       msg += "arguments[" + i + "] = " + arguments[i] + "\n";

   msg += "And arguments.callee.toString() is the function's literal body in string format = \n" + arguments.callee.toString() + "\n";

   alert(msg);
}

function parent()
{
   show_props(1,2,3);
}

parent();

The result is shown below:

function name = show_props
called from = parent
arguments.length = 3 argument(s) were passed.
show_props.length (arity) = 5 argument(s) are defined total.
arguments = [object Arguments]
arguments[0] = 1
arguments[1] = 2
arguments[2] = 3
And arguments.callee.toString() is the function's literal body in string format = 
function show_props(a,b,c,d,e)
{
   var msg = "function name = " + arguments.callee.name + "\n";
   msg += "called from = " + show_props.caller.name + "\n";
   msg += "arguments.length = " + arguments.length + " argument(s) were passed.\n"
   msg += "show_props.length (arity) = " + show_props.length + " argument(s) are defined total.\n";
   msg += "arguments = " + arguments +  "\n";
   for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
       msg += "arguments[" + i + "] = " + arguments[i] + "\n";

   msg += "And arguments.callee.toString() is the function's literal body in string format = \n" + arguments.callee.toString() + "\n";

   alert("msg");
```